# if statement doesn't check the values of the edittexts reached by scrolling the recyclerview

Tags: android-recyclerview, xamarin.android, android-edittext

i have a recyclerview the has an edittext in each row. the user can change the value of the edittext as he wishes but it should not be left empty for the values will be saved in a database. for this i'm trying to check if the edittext is empty. if any row has an empty edittext, the user is given a message when he wants to save that there is an empty value. this is the code that i wrote:

```
  public class recyclerview_viewholder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        {
            public TextView rownbr, itemname;
            public EditText qty;
            public TextView unit;
            public LinearLayout linearLayout;
           
            public recyclerview_viewholder(View itemView, Action<int> listener)
              : base(itemView)
            {
                rownbr = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.rownbr);
                itemname = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.laborname);
                unit = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.days);
                qty = itemView.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.overtime);
                linearLayout = itemView.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linearLayout);
               
                itemView.Click += (sender, e) => listener(base.LayoutPosition);
               
            }
        }

        public class recyclerviewAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
        {
            // Event handler for item clicks:
            public event EventHandler<int> ItemClick;

            DataTable summary_Requests = new DataTable();
            //Context context;
            public readonly new_request_items context;
            int selected_pos = -1;
            private SwipeToDeleteCallback swipeToDeleteCallback;
            List<list_item> item_details = new List<list_item>();
            public recyclerviewAdapter(new_request_items context, DataTable sum_req, List<list_item> item_details)
            {
                this.context = context;
                summary_Requests = sum_req;
                this.item_details = item_details;

            }
            public recyclerviewAdapter(DataTable sum_req, SwipeToDeleteCallback swipeToDeleteCallback)
            {
                this.swipeToDeleteCallback = swipeToDeleteCallback;
                summary_Requests = sum_req;

            }
            public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder
                   OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
            {
                View itemView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).
                            Inflate(Resource.Layout.recycler_view_request_new_data, parent, false);


                recyclerview_viewholder vh = new recyclerview_viewholder(itemView, OnClick);

                vh.qty.TextChanged += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    if (vh.qty.Text != "")

                        try
                        {
                            int position = vh.LayoutPosition;
                            summary_Requests.Rows[position]["itemQty"] = Convert.ToDecimal(vh.qty.Text);
                            user.zero_val = "Not_exist";
                        }
                        catch (System.FormatException exp)
                        {
                            var icon = AppCompatResources.GetDrawable(context.Context, Resource.Drawable.error_ic);
                            icon.SetBounds(0, 0, 50, 50);
                            vh.qty.SetError("qty can be decimal", icon);
                            user.zero_val = "exits";
                        }
                    else if (vh.qty.Text == "")
                    {
                        var icon = AppCompatResources.GetDrawable(context.Context, Resource.Drawable.error_ic);
                        icon.SetBounds(0, 0, 50, 50);
                        vh.qty.SetError("value can not be empty", icon);
                        user.zero_val = "exits";
                    }

                };
                vh.ItemView.LongClick += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    int position = vh.AdapterPosition;
                    string itemcode = summary_Requests.Rows[position]["itemcode"].ToString();


                    list_item result = item_details.Find(list_item => list_item.item_code == itemcode);
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.PutString("result", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result));
                    items_info iteminf = new items_info();
                    iteminf.Arguments = bundle;
                    iteminf.Cancelable = true;
                    var SupportFragmentManager = this.context.FragmentManager;
                    iteminf.Show(SupportFragmentManager, "dialog");
               
                    selected_pos = position;
                    NotifyDataSetChanged();
                    //fill global variables that need to be passed to detail fragment



                };

                return vh;
            }
            public override void
                  OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
            {
                recyclerview_viewholder vh = holder as recyclerview_viewholder;

              
                vh.rownbr.Text = summary_Requests.Rows[position]["rowNumber"].ToString();
                vh.itemname.Text = summary_Requests.Rows[position]["name"].ToString();
                vh.unit.Text = summary_Requests.Rows[position]["itemsunitcode"].ToString();
                vh.qty.Text= summary_Requests.Rows[position]["itemQty"].ToString();
                if (selected_pos == position)
                    vh.ItemView.SetBackgroundColor(Color.ParseColor("#4fa5d5"));
                else
                    vh.ItemView.SetBackgroundColor(Color.LightGray);

               
            }



            public void RemoveItem(int position)
            {
                
                if (laborers_dt_total.Rows.Count != 0)
                {
                    if (position < laborers_dt_total.Rows.Count && position > -1)
                    {
                        laborers_dt_total.Rows.RemoveAt(position);
                     
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.MakeText(context.Context, "select an item to delete", ToastLength.Long).Show();

                    }

                }
                else if (laborers_dt_total.Rows.Count == 0)
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(context.Context, "no items to delete", ToastLength.Long).Show();

                }


                for (int i = 0; i < laborers_dt_total.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    laborers_dt_total.Rows[i]["rowNumber"] = (i + 1).ToString();
                   
                    NotifyDataSetChanged();
                    
                }

            }
            public DataTable get_dt_final()
            {
                DataTable final_dt = summary_Requests.Copy();
                return final_dt;
            }
            public override int ItemCount
            {
                get { return summary_Requests.Rows.Count; }
            }
            // Raise an event when the item-click takes place:
            void OnClick(int position)
            {
                if (ItemClick != null)
                    ItemClick(this, position);
                // user.req_pos = position;


            }
         

        }
```

now it works well when there are only few rows in the recyclerview, but when there are many in which i have to scroll through it, if i keep an edittext empty in a row reached by scrolling, the `user.zero_val` doesn't take the value of `exits` to tell me that an edittext is empty. what should i do in this case? where do i check for empty edittext? thanks in advance.

this is a simple code i wrote with hopes it would illustrate my problem:

this is the axml of the recyclerview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="255sp"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView1" />
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button1" />


</LinearLayout>
```

this is the layout of each row of the recyclerview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"                    
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/light_grey"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0.5dp"
        android:weightSum="8"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    
                >
    
    <TextView
        android:text=""
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:id="@+id/rownbr" 
        android:background="@drawable/back"
        android:paddingLeft="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="1dp"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
    />
    <TextView
        android:text=""
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:id="@+id/laborname" 
        android:paddingLeft="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="1dp"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="@drawable/back"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:text=""
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/days" 
        android:paddingLeft="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="1dp"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/back"/>
    
    <EditText
        android:text=""
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/overtime" 
        android:paddingLeft="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="1dp"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/back"/>
        
</LinearLayout>
```

this is the back.xml drawable:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
  <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
  <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#4fa5d5"/>
</shape>
```

this is the activity where the recyclerview is populated and managed:

```
 public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
       
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
        recyclerviewAdapter RecyclerviewAdapter;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
            dt.Columns.Add("rowNumber");
            dt.Columns.Add("name");
            dt.Columns.Add("itemsunitcode");
            dt.Columns.Add("itemQty");

            dt.Rows.Add("1", "rana hd", "pcs", "1");
            dt.Rows.Add("2", "rana hd1", "pcs", "1");
            dt.Rows.Add("3", "rana hd2", "pcs", "1");
            dt.Rows.Add("4", "rana hd3", "pcs", "1");
            dt.Rows.Add("5", "rana hd4", "pcs", "1");
            dt.Rows.Add("6", "rana hd5", "pcs", "1");
            dt.Rows.Add("7", "rana hd6", "pcs", "1");
            dt.Rows.Add("8", "rana hd7", "pcs", "1");
            dt.Rows.Add("9", "rana hd8", "pcs", "1");
            dt.Rows.Add("10", "rana hd9", "pcs", "1");
          
          
            mRecyclerView = FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.recyclerView1);
            Button btn= FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
            mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
            mRecyclerView.HasFixedSize = true;
            mRecyclerView.SetLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
            RecyclerviewAdapter = new recyclerviewAdapter(this, dt);
            mRecyclerView.SetAdapter(RecyclerviewAdapter);

            btn.Click += delegate
            {
                if (user.zero_val == "exits")
                    Toast.MakeText(this, "exists", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                if (user.zero_val == "Not_exist")
                    Toast.MakeText(this, "Not_exist", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            };
        }
        public class recyclerview_viewholder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        {
            public TextView rownbr, itemname;
            public EditText qty;
            public TextView unit;
            public LinearLayout linearLayout;

            public recyclerview_viewholder(View itemView, Action<int> listener)
              : base(itemView)
            {
                rownbr = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.rownbr);
                itemname = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.laborname);
                unit = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.days);
                qty = itemView.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.overtime);
                linearLayout = itemView.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linearLayout);

                itemView.Click += (sender, e) => listener(base.LayoutPosition);

            }
        }

        public class recyclerviewAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
        {
            // Event handler for item clicks:
            public event EventHandler<int> ItemClick;

            DataTable summary_Requests = new DataTable();
            //Context context;
            public readonly MainActivity context;
            int selected_pos = -1;
             public recyclerviewAdapter(MainActivity context, DataTable sum_req)
            {
                this.context = context;
                summary_Requests = sum_req;
             
            }
          
            public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder
                   OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
            {
                View itemView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).
                            Inflate(Resource.Layout.recyclerview_data, parent, false);


                recyclerview_viewholder vh = new recyclerview_viewholder(itemView, OnClick);

                vh.qty.TextChanged += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    if (vh.qty.Text != "")

                        try
                        {
                            int position = vh.LayoutPosition;
                            summary_Requests.Rows[position]["itemQty"] = Convert.ToDecimal(vh.qty.Text);
                            user.zero_val = "Not_exist";
                        }
                        catch (System.FormatException exp)
                        {
                            var icon = AppCompatResources.GetDrawable(context, Resource.Drawable.error_ic);
                            icon.SetBounds(0, 0, 50, 50);
                            vh.qty.SetError("qty can be decimal", icon);
                            user.zero_val = "exits";
                        }
                    else if (vh.qty.Text == "")
                    {
                        var icon = AppCompatResources.GetDrawable(context, Resource.Drawable.error_ic);
                        icon.SetBounds(0, 0, 50, 50);
                        vh.qty.SetError("value can not be empty", icon);
                        user.zero_val = "exits";
                    }

                };
                vh.ItemView.LongClick += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    int position = vh.AdapterPosition;
                  
                    selected_pos = position;
                    NotifyDataSetChanged();
                
                };

                return vh;
            }
            public override void
                  OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
            {
                recyclerview_viewholder vh = holder as recyclerview_viewholder;


                vh.rownbr.Text = summary_Requests.Rows[position]["rowNumber"].ToString();
                vh.itemname.Text = summary_Requests.Rows[position]["name"].ToString();
                vh.unit.Text = summary_Requests.Rows[position]["itemsunitcode"].ToString();
                vh.qty.Text = summary_Requests.Rows[position]["itemQty"].ToString();
                if (selected_pos == position)
                    vh.ItemView.SetBackgroundColor(Color.ParseColor("#4fa5d5"));
                else
                    vh.ItemView.SetBackgroundColor(Color.LightGray);
            }
         
            public DataTable get_dt_final()
            {
                DataTable final_dt = summary_Requests.Copy();
                return final_dt;
            }
            public override int ItemCount
            {
                get { return summary_Requests.Rows.Count; }
            }
            // Raise an event when the item-click takes place:
            void OnClick(int position)
            {
                if (ItemClick != null)
                    ItemClick(this, position);
                // user.req_pos = position;


            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is the user class:

```
 public static class user
    {
        public static string zero_val = "";
    }
```

Comment: `vh.rownbr.Text = summary_Requests.Rows[position]["rowNumber"].ToString();`   What do you mean by above code ? If it is convinient for you, could you please post a basic demo to github or onedriver so that we can help you better?

Comment: thanks a lot for replying. my recyclerview has 3 textviews and one edittext in each row. the textviews' values are gotten from a database. thanks a lot for the suggestion. i've never posted on github i'll see how it's done and tell you.

Comment: Hi @rana,any updates?

Comment: hello @JessieZhang-MSFT, thanks a lot for your concern. i wrote a more simple code but i didn't know how to share it on github. i posted it here. please tell me if it helps.

Comment: What's the `DataTable` ? What Nuget have you installed?

Comment: Besides, you can also upload your demo to onedriver and share your link here.

Comment: ```Datatable``` is implemented using ```System.Data```  (assembly)

Comment: `the user.zero_val doesn't take the value of exits to tell me that an edittext is empty` After  I tested your code , I found the EditText could pop up the alert that the EditText is empty and there is also a error icon beside it.

Comment: yes, it does. but when you scroll down and empty an edittext then scroll up and click the button, you get a toast that says "Not_exits" which means that the empty edittext was not detected

Comment: According to your steps, I could just get a toast says `exists` not `Not_exits` .  What are you trying to achieve?  In addition, we should use method `Equals` to compare two strings not  `==` .

Comment: i don't want the user to be capable of doing anything if there is an empty cell in the recyclerview so i'm trying to detect when there is an empty edittext. when i keep an empty edittext for example in the last row in the recyclerview that i reached by scrolling, and then scroll up without filling it then i click the button, i get Not_exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I undstand your meanings correctly, I don't think it's correct to use variable `zero_val` in class `user` to indicate whether or not null values exist.For example ,if you have enter a empty value for the first EditText, then the value of `zero_val` will been changed to `Not_exist`, then if we enter another empty value for the second EditText, then the value of `zero_val` will also been changed to `Not_exist`,after that, if we change the second EditText to a correct value, then the value of `zero_val` will been changed to `exits`.But now, actually the first EditText still be empty.

I think you can verify the values the table `DataTable` when clicking button.

You can refer to the following code:

```
        btn.Click += delegate
        {
            bool hasEmpty = false ;
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                string itemQty = row["itemQty"].ToString();
                string rowNumber = row["rowNumber"].ToString();

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("rowNumber =" + rowNumber  + "< ---  > itemQty = " + itemQty);
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(itemQty)) {
                    hasEmpty = true;
                }
            }

            //if (user.zero_val.Equals("exits"))
            //    Toast.MakeText(this, "exists", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            //if (user.zero_val.Equals("Not_exist"))
            //    Toast.MakeText(this, "Not_exist", ToastLength.Long).Show();

            if (!hasEmpty)
                Toast.MakeText(this, "exists", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            else
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Not_exist", ToastLength.Long).Show();
        };
```

In addition, modify the `TextChanged` function in `RecyclerviewAdapter`:

```
        vh.qty.TextChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (!vh.qty.Text.Equals(""))

                try
                {
                    int position = vh.LayoutPosition;
                    summary_Requests.Rows[position]["itemQty"] = Convert.ToDecimal(vh.qty.Text);
                }
                catch (System.FormatException exp)
                {
                    var icon = AppCompatResources.GetDrawable(context, Resource.Drawable.error);
                    icon.SetBounds(0, 0, 50, 50);
                    vh.qty.SetError("qty can be decimal", icon);

                    //store a empty value for this textview
                    int position = vh.LayoutPosition;
                    summary_Requests.Rows[position]["itemQty"] = "";
                }
            else if (vh.qty.Text.Equals(""))
            {
                var icon = AppCompatResources.GetDrawable(context, Resource.Drawable.error);
                int position = vh.LayoutPosition;

                //store a empty value for this textview
                summary_Requests.Rows[position]["itemQty"] = "";

                icon.SetBounds(0, 0, 50, 50);
                vh.qty.SetError("value can not be empty", icon);

            }
        };
```

Comment: thanks a lot for helping me. that's very nice of you. it worked well.